# What year did bitcoins come out?

Tags: wallet-recovery, history

I purchased one in 2009 or 2010 . I want to know how I would recover it. I was sent to prison I would like to know asap please and thank you .

Answer (score 1):

The Bitcoin network was launched in early 2009.

To recover your coins, you'll need to find the wallet file that contains your private keys. You'll need to remember how you stored your Bitcoin, did you have a run wallet on a personal computer? etc. Remembering the answer to that question is probably your only hope of recovering your Bitcoin.

Without any additional info, I don't think there is any way that anyone here can help you further than that.

Comment: No other wallets existed at that time. It’s likely if this story is true, they are misremembering.